# Sending a file as an attachment to the Response in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

This question is similar to this [old question](https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/Download.20files.20with.20resteasy-reactive) but I have gone through it as well as the Quarkus [feature request](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/15891) relating to this topic with no luck.

Below is the code of my downstream method which attempts to return a file as an attachment to the response so it can be downloaded by the user after hitting a route from the application. The commented section is a second attempt using the StreamingOutput.

I am getting this error currently:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.fanthreesixty.audience.resource.S3ClientResource$$Lambda$2984/0x0000000801f44000 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

My question is, am I using StreamingOutput correctly with Quarkus or is there another way I should be doing this in order to achieve what I am trying to do? Thank you for your time.

```
public Response downloadFile(final String bucketName, final String objectKey, final String fileExtension) {
        try {

            CompletableFuture<ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>> response = s3.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .build(), AsyncResponseTransformer.toBlockingInputStream());

            final String fileName = objectKey.contains("/") ? objectKey.split("/")[1] : objectKey;

//            StreamingOutput stream = outputStream -> {
//                try (InputStream is = response.join()) {
//                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
//                    int bytesRead;
//                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
//                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
//                    }
//                }
//            };

            StreamingOutput stream = output -> output.write(response.join().readAllBytes());

            return Response.ok(stream)
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not create FileOutputStream due to error", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Streaming output should not be supported is quarkus 2.x

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci can you add that as a proper answer with a link to the feature for Quarkus 3? That will help future readers so they don't have to read comments.

Answer (score 0):

`StreamingOutput` is not supported in Quarkus 2.x.
Support has been added since release 3.x ([Add support for JAX-RS StreamingOutput in RESTEasy Reactive](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/30945))

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Quarkus 2. This example pulls a file from S3 and saves it to a temporary location. You then create an InputStream and copy the file and return it in a regular Response object. NOTE: I know the S3 code I have here is not following the docs but this is how I was able to get it to work.

Without the S3 stuff, the core part is getting a `java.nio.file.Path` to the file and then returning it with the `toFile` method to the Response object.

```java
CompletableFuture<ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>> response = s3.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder()
           .bucket(bucketName)
           .key(objectKey)
           .build(), AsyncResponseTransformer.toBlockingInputStream());
final String fileName = objectKey.contains("/") ? objectKey.split("/")[1] : objectKey;
final String temporaryFolderPath = "/tmp/downloads/";
java.nio.file.Path tmpFilePath = Paths.get(temporaryFolderPath, fileName + fileExtension);
try (InputStream is = response.join()) {
    Files.createDirectories(tmpFilePath.getParent());
    Files.copy(is, tmpFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    return Response.ok(tmpFilePath.toFile())
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".zip\"")
        .build();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Could not write downloaded S3 resource to File", e);
}
```